# Javascript - How to cycle through 7 days & also get todays date if current UTC time is past midnight

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a JSON object like this

```
"storeHours":{  
      "friday":{  
         "close":"23:45",
         "notes":"Walk-Ins Only",
         "open":"14:00"
      },
      "monday":{  
         "close":null,
         "notes":null,
         "open":null
      },
      "saturday":{  
         "close":"20:00",
         "notes":"Walk-Ins Only",
         "open":"13:00"
      },
      "sunday":{  
         "close":null,
         "notes":null,
         "open":null
      },
      "thursday":{  
         "close":"23:45",
         "notes":"Appointments & Walk-Ins",
         "open":"14:00"
      },
      "tuesday":{  
         "close":"23:45",
         "notes":"Walk-Ins Only",
         "open":"14:00"
      },
      "wednesday":{  
         "close":"23:45",
         "notes":"Walk-Ins Only",
         "open":"14:00"
      }
```

The open and close times are in UTC (I'm working from Pennsylvania EST).

I have a Javascript function that creates a new Date() object, and loops 7 times, increasing the day of the Date() object. During each loop I reference the open and close times to build a new JSON Object that looks like this.

```
{  
   "friday":{  
      "close":"2016-01-08T23:45:00.000Z",
      "notes":"Walk-Ins Only",
      "open":"2016-01-08T14:00:00.000Z"
   },
   "monday":{  
      "close":null,
      "notes":null,
      "open":null
   },
   "saturday":{  
      "close":"2016-01-09T20:00:00.000Z",
      "notes":"Walk-Ins Only",
      "open":"2016-01-09T13:00:00.000Z"
   },
   "sunday":{  
      "close":null,
      "notes":null,
      "open":null
   },
   "thursday":{  
      "close":"2016-01-14T23:45:00.000Z",
      "notes":"Appointments & Walk-Ins",
      "open":"2016-01-14T14:00:00.000Z"
   },
   "tuesday":{  
      "close":"2016-01-12T23:45:00.000Z",
      "notes":"Walk-Ins Only",
      "open":"2016-01-12T14:00:00.000Z"
   },
   "wednesday":{  
      "close":"2016-01-13T23:45:00.000Z",
      "notes":"Walk-Ins Only",
      "open":"2016-01-13T14:00:00.000Z"
   }
}
```

My problem is when UTC time goes past midnight, my loop ends up giving me today (Thursday) as January 14th. I need to come up with a way so I get today (January 7th) plus the rest of the days. How can I accomplish this?

How can I use EST with these dates?

Comment: make sure you are parsing the date with timezone info included, that way it won't matter what time of day it is in england...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. It sounds like your issue is with your "_Javascript function that creates a new Date() object, and loops 7 times_", so why not post that as well? If I understand correctly, your final data structure is correct, except you expect your `"thursday"` object to have open/close times of today, the 7th, instead of next thursday, the 14th?

Comment: @rgthree You are correct, I didn't post the method because it was just a while loop with a 7 counter, I think the issue is just with the timezone. I am working on a way to somehow convert the initial Date() object to EST before i start creating the final JSON object. Its parsing the times in as UTC which is why i dont get January 7th EST, but im getting January 8th as today